# Problems with multiple wallets on RPC in bitcoin-core

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, bitcoind, json-rpc, python

I have been playing around a bit with Bitcoin Core (version 23.0), more specifically connecting to different wallets in Bitcoin Core through RPC in Python. I have found [this](https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc) library and tried to connect to my wallet(s) using this code:

```
from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy

conn = AuthServiceProxy("http://myusername:mypassword@127.0.0.1:18332/wallet/testingwallet")
print(conn.getwalletinfo())
```

But when running this i get this stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kebab/Desktop/pron/testing.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(a.getwalletinfo())
  File "/home/kebab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bitcoinrpc/authproxy.py", line 141, in __call__
    raise JSONRPCException(response['error'])
bitcoinrpc.authproxy.JSONRPCException: -18: Requested wallet does not exist or is not loaded
```

Though what I have noticed is that if i load the wallet using `bitcoin-cli -testnet loadwallet testingwallet`. Then i can run RPC commands but only get info from that wallet!

And I have created my wallet using: `bitcoin-cli -testnet createwallet testingwallet`

Any help on this would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the wallet into bitcoin core before you can use it. So first, load all the wallets you want to use with `bitcoin-cli loadwallet`. To verify the loaded wallets, you can use `bitcoin-cli listwallets`

After you have loaded the wallets you can specify the wallet in the connection. The format is `<RPC IP address>:<RPC port>/wallet/<wallet name>`, for example `https://127.0.0.1:8332/wallet/wallet1.dat`.

Info from wiki https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#Multi-wallet_RPC_calls and this discussion https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5398213.0